# Semitransperent fireing zone for shooter game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opengl

I'm coding shooter game. Now, I'm trying to draw fireing zone for player when he is targeting. For this task I decide to use GL.

So I wrote code for drawing zone polygon but it don't want to be semi-transparent.

```
sealed public class Player : Dweller, IHitable, IAttacker
    {
...
private void SetWeapon(Weapon prefab)
        {
            if (!weapon)
            {
                weapon = Instantiate(prefab, hand);
                Camera.onPostRender += FiringZoneHilighter;
            }
        }

 bool highlight = false;
        public void TakeAim(Joystick joystick, Vector2 forward, bool fire)
        {
            highlight = false;
            if (fire)
            {
                CmdAttack();

            }
            else
            {
                SetRotation(forward);
                highlight = true;
            }
        }

private void FiringZoneHilighter(Camera cam)
        {
            if (!highlight) return;
            if (!cam.GetComponent<PlayerFollower>()) return;

            if (!aimVizualizationMaterial)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Material for aim vizualization isn't set");
                return;
            }
            //Debug.Log("Drawing");
            Vector3 weaponPos = weapon.transform.position;
            float spread = weapon.AttackSpread;
            float range = weapon.Range;
            Vector3 direction = transform.forward;

            aimVizualizationMaterial.SetPass(0);


            GL.Begin(GL.TRIANGLES);
            GL.Color(new Color(0.1f, 1f, 0.2f, 0.3f));


            Vector3 nextPoint = weaponPos + direction.RotateAroundY(-spread / 2) * range;
            Vector3 rightFarthestPoint;
            int points = 1000;

            float spreadPart = spread / points;
            for (int i = 0; i != points; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(weaponPos.x, weaponPos.y, weaponPos.z);

                rightFarthestPoint = nextPoint;
                nextPoint = weaponPos + direction.RotateAroundY(i * spreadPart - spread / 2) * range;
                GL.Vertex3(rightFarthestPoint.x, rightFarthestPoint.y, rightFarthestPoint.z);
                GL.Vertex3(nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y, nextPoint.z);
            }

            GL.End();


        }
...
}
```

I even can't understand which type of shader I should use for material. Most of the time it staying invisible. If'm deleting *.SetPass(0) zone becomes grey. In this case when player shoots (shoot have animation particle), somewhere in animation life cicle GL draws zone. After paticle ends zone becomes grey again.

Maybe there is another more easier way to draw this zone whitou GL?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what exactly is a `fireing zone`?

Comment: It is visualization of weapon shot dispersion.